# iPhone: detect two finger touch

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need to detect two finger touch event. If i touch the screen with two fingers on same time, so everthing is ok. Just using such code:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  UITouch *touch = [[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
  CGPoint point1 = [touch locationInView:self];
  CGPoint point2 ; 
  NSLog(@"First: %f %f", point1.x, point1.y) ; 
  if ([[touches allObjects] count] > 1) {
    UITouch *touch2 = [[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:1];
    point2 = [touch2 locationInView:self];
    NSLog(@"Second: %f %f", point2.x, point2.y) ;   
  }
}
```

But this code don't working if i hold one finger and then touch the screen with another finger. How to implement this ? Is it hard to do ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Make sure the UIView has `multipleTouchEnabled=YES`, the default is `NO`.

Edit:I see what the problem is. In touchesBegan:withEvent:, you will only get the new touches. You don't get all the active touches. It is very unlikely, if at all possible, that you will get more than one touch to begin at the same time. To check is there is more than one active touch int touchesBegan: try this:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    if ([[event touchesForView:self] count] > 1) {
        NSLog(@"%d active touches",[[event touchesForView:self.view] count]) ;


    }
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event] ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but not helps. I added to View Controller: [self.view setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES] ; I even added for testing purposes [self setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES] in touchesBegan.

Comment: Where did you add [self.view setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES]?

Comment: Thanks for replay. i'm adding [self.view setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES] in viewDidLoad

Comment: That is the correct place. Is self.view (the controller's view) the one that is receiving the touches? Is there any subview?

Comment: No i don't use any other subviews. Your can download simple project from http://dl.dropbox.com/u/11760459/touch.zip . The problem: then i hold one finger and touch another finger touchesBegan triggered only for one finger.

Comment: Minor issue, but you'd want to change touchesForView:self with touchesForView:self.view

Comment: The method touchesBegan:withEvent: handles events both in the view and in the controller. As it is (and as posed in the question) is the view's method. It is not an error, both ways are correct depending on the class the method is implemented in.

Answer (score 1):

What is the real object that is receiving the event? That object may get your touch event and not the base UIResponder.

For example if you are inside a UIScroolView then you can get the sec touch in: 
 - (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;

Comment: Thanks, but i don't need zooming. I just want everything implement with touchesBegan, touchesMoved, touchesEnded. This method returns UIView so it's not suitable for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch1, *touch2;
    CGPoint    location1, location2;

    NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];
    touch1 = [[allTouches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
    location1 = [touch1 locationInView:self];

    if([allTouches count] > 1)
    {
        touch2 = [[allTouches allObjects] objectAtIndex:1];
        location2 = [touch2 locationInView:self];
    }
}
```